# Testing a POST Api using Junit and Mockito-Nested Exception problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, mockmvc

I am trying to test an API using JUNIT and mockito, being a beginner i didn't find any solution regarding the problem i am stating

I am trying to test an api which invovles the inclusion of employee and department in the form of

```
{
        "name": "ABC",
        "age": 20,
        "salary": 2500.0,
        "departmentTest": {
            "deptId": 5,
            "deptName": "Developer"
        }
    }
```

This should be body of the post request.
    Here there is a many to one mapping between Employee and Department. Many employee can belong to one department and the mapping is bi directional.

I am getting the following exception:-

```
**org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.controller.EmployeeTestController.addEmployee(EmployeeTestController.java:45)**
```

Hereby i am attaching Controller,Service and Testing file:-

Controller file:-

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeTestController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeTestService employeeTestService;

    @GetMapping("/employee")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllEmployee()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeTestService.getAllEmployee(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeTestDTO employeeTestDTO) throws EmployeeException
    {
        if(employeeTestDTO.getSalary() <= 0 ){
            throw new EmployeeException("Salary Should be greater than Zero");
        }
        else {
            employeeTestService.addEmployee(employeeTestDTO);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
    }

}
```

Service File:-

```
@Service
public class EmployeeTestService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeTestRespository employeeTestRespository;

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentTestService departmentTestService;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public List<EmployeeTestDTO> getAllEmployee()
    {
        List<EmployeeTestDTO> empDTO = new ArrayList<EmployeeTestDTO>();
        List<EmployeeTest> emp=employeeTestRespository.findAll();
        for(EmployeeTest e : emp)
        {
            empDTO.add(modelMapper.map(e, EmployeeTestDTO.class));
        }

        return empDTO;
    }

    public Object getIndividualEmployee(Integer id) throws  EmployeeException {
        Optional<EmployeeTest> op_employeeTest = employeeTestRespository.findById(id);
        if(op_employeeTest.isPresent())
        {
            return modelMapper.map(op_employeeTest.get(), EmployeeTestDTO.class);

        }
        else
        {
            throw new EmployeeException("No such employee exist");
        }
    }

    public void addEmployee(EmployeeTestDTO employeeTestDTO) throws EmployeeException {
         String dept_name = modelMapper.map(employeeTestDTO, EmployeeTest.class).getDepartmentTest().getDeptName();
         DepartmentTest departmentTest = departmentTestService.findDepartmentByDeptName(dept_name);
         if(departmentTest == null){
             throw new EmployeeException("Department doesn't exist");
         }
         else {
             EmployeeTest employeeTest = modelMapper.map(employeeTestDTO,EmployeeTest.class);
             employeeTest.setDepartmentTest(departmentTest);
             employeeTestRespository.save(employeeTest);
         }
    }
```

Testing File:-

```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @WebMvcTest(controllers = EmployeeTestController.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestingForEmployeeApplication.class)
   public class ControllerTesting {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @MockBean
        private EmployeeTestService employeeTestService;

        @InjectMocks
        private EmployeeTestController employeeTestController;

        @MockBean
        private ModelMapper modelMapper;


        DepartmentTest departmentTest ;
        EmployeeTest employeeTest;

        @Before
        public void setUp()throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println("Inside Set Up Method");
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeeTestController)
                        .build();
            departmentTest = new DepartmentTest();
            departmentTest.setDeptId(1);
            departmentTest.setDeptName("Sales");

        }

        @Test
        public void controllerTesting() throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println(departmentTest.getDeptId());
            System.out.println(departmentTest.getDeptName());

               String json =  "{\"name\":\"ABC\",\"age\":20,\"salary\":2500,\"departmentTest\":{\"deptId\":5,\"deptName\":\"Developer\"}}";
               mockMvc.perform(post("/employee")
                       .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                       .content(json))
                       .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", Matchers.is("ABC")))
                       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.age", Matchers.is(20)))
                       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.salary", Matchers.is(2500)));


        }   


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null pointer for `employeeTestService`.

It means `employeeTestService` is not getting injected from your Testing file.

I think you missed initMocks in `setup()` method

```
@Before
public void setUp()throws Exception
{

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    System.out.println("Inside Set Up Method");
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeeTestController)
                .build();
    departmentTest = new DepartmentTest();
    departmentTest.setDeptId(1);
    departmentTest.setDeptName("Sales");
}
```